# How to configure two servers with different IP in different networks into one cluster in Dask?

Tags: python, docker, dask, distributed-computing, dask-distributed

I'm trying to set up Dask cluster with docker containers of nodes in different networks.

Here is my simplified configurations with one worker. (public IP is randomly written)

#### Node configurations

##### 1. Node 1 (Scheduler)

1. Docker instance 
   IP: 172.17.0.2 
   Scheduler port: 8786 
   Dashboard port: 8787
2. Host 
   IP: 123.456.78.910 (public IP) 
   Forwarding port: 28786(8786), 28787(8787) 
   **Open for all ports**

##### 2. Node 2 (Worker)

1. Docker instance 
   IP: 172.17.0.2 
   Worker port: 8786
2. Host 
   IP: 123.456.78.911 (public IP) 
   Forwarding port: 28786 
   **Open for specific ports(22, 28786, 28787, ..)** ← I think this might be the cause of the problem

#### Tried

##### 1. Register worker to scheduler

```
// Scheduler container terminal

$ dask-scheduler
distributed.scheduler - INFO - -----------------------------------------------
distributed.scheduler - INFO - -----------------------------------------------
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Clear task state
distributed.scheduler - INFO -   Scheduler at:     tcp://172.17.0.2:8786
distributed.scheduler - INFO -   dashboard at:                     :8787
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Register worker <WorkerState 'tcp://172.17.0.2:28786', name: tcp://172.17.0.2:28786, memory: 0, processing: 0>
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Starting worker compute stream, tcp://172.17.0.2:28786
distributed.core - INFO - Starting established connection
```

```
// Worker container terminal

$ dask-worker 123.456.78.910:28786 --worker-port 28786 --no-nanny
distributed.worker - INFO -       Start worker at:     tcp://172.17.0.2:28786
distributed.worker - INFO -          Listening to:     tcp://172.17.0.2:28786
distributed.worker - INFO -          dashboard at:           172.17.0.2:43989
distributed.worker - INFO - Waiting to connect to: tcp://123.456.78.910:28786
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
distributed.worker - INFO -               Threads:                         40
distributed.worker - INFO -                Memory:                 502.55 GiB
distributed.worker - INFO -       Local Directory: /root/dask-worker-space/worker-y9tym3ma
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
distributed.worker - INFO -         Registered to: tcp://123.456.78.910:28786
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
distributed.core - INFO - Starting established connection
```

I think the **address(172.17.0.2)** should be **123.456.78.911** in the scheduler log

`distributed.scheduler - INFO - Register worker <WorkerState 'tcp://172.17.0.2:28786', name: tcp://172.17.0.2:28786, memory: 0, processing: 0>`

but, adding the `host` option does not work.

```
// Worker container terminal

$ dask-worker 123.456.78.910:28786 --host 123.456.78.911 --worker-port 28786 --no-nanny
distributed.dask_worker - INFO - End worker
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/bin/dask-worker", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('distributed==2021.9.1', 'console_scripts', 'dask-worker')())
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/cli/dask_worker.py", line 465, in go
    main()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/cli/dask_worker.py", line 451, in main
    loop.run_sync(run)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 530, in run_sync
    return future_cell[0].result()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/cli/dask_worker.py", line 445, in run
    await asyncio.gather(*nannies)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 695, in _wrap_awaitable
    return (yield from awaitable.__await__())
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 283, in _
    await self.start()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 1172, in start
    await self.listen(start_address, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/core.py", line 401, in listen
    listener = await listen(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/comm/core.py", line 206, in _
    await self.start()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 470, in start
    sockets = netutil.bind_sockets(
  File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 161, in bind_sockets
    sock.bind(sockaddr)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

##### 2. Python script

```
// This script is run in Scheduler container

from dask import Client

client = Client("localhost:8786")
print(client)

names   = [str(i) for i in range(10)]
futures = client.map(lambda name: f"task-{name}", names, key=names)
results = client.gather(futures)


############### Blocked in here ###############


print("\n- Results")
for i in results:
    print(i)
```

```
// Python output

- Distributed scheduler:<Client: 'tcp://172.17.0.2:8786' processes=1 threads=40, memory=502.55 GiB>
distributed.client - WARNING - Couldn't gather 10 keys, rescheduling {'0': ('tcp://172.17.0.2:28786',), '8': ('tcp://172.17.0.2:28786',), '2': ('tcp://172.17.0.2:28786',), '4': ('tcp://172.17.0.2:28786',), '1': ('tcp://172.17.0.2:28786',), '9': ('tcp://172.17.0.2:28786',), '5': ('tcp://172.17.0.2:28786',), '6': ('tcp://172.17.0.2:28786',), '7': ('tcp://172.17.0.2:28786',), '3': ('tcp://172.17.0.2:28786',)}
```

```
// Scheduler output

distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Couldn't gather keys {'0': ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], '8': ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], '2': ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], '4': ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], '1': ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], '9': ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], '5': ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], '6': ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], '7': ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], '3': ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786']} state: ['memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory', 'memory'] workers: ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786']
NoneType: None
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Remove worker <WorkerState 'tcp://172.17.0.2:28786', name: tcp://172.17.0.2:28786, memory: 10, processing: 0>
distributed.core - INFO - Removing comms to tcp://172.17.0.2:28786
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Lost all workers
distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Workers don't have promised key: ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], 0
NoneType: None
distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Workers don't have promised key: ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], 8
NoneType: None
distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Workers don't have promised key: ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], 2
NoneType: None
distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Workers don't have promised key: ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], 4
NoneType: None
distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Workers don't have promised key: ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], 1
NoneType: None
distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Workers don't have promised key: ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], 9
NoneType: None
distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Workers don't have promised key: ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], 5
NoneType: None
distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Workers don't have promised key: ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], 6
NoneType: None
distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Workers don't have promised key: ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], 7
NoneType: None
distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Workers don't have promised key: ['tcp://172.17.0.2:28786'], 3
NoneType: None
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Register worker <WorkerState 'tcp://172.17.0.2:28786', name: tcp://172.17.0.2:28786, memory: 10, processing: 0>
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Starting worker compute stream, tcp://172.17.0.2:28786
distributed.core - INFO - Starting established connection
```

It seems the connection between the scheduler and the worker is not good.

How can I connect docker containers in other networks?